# inserting line of code in the same module according to user input

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to insert new lines of codes in the same running module every time the user input something. I tried with open function but this function in exe program will open a new file to write the user input in it and that will not help me. basically, I want user input to be added as a line of code in the same module that the application is running on. "note: Addingpage is another module that I use to add user input in it" here is my application:

```
`    def addingfunction(self):
        Name = self.name_add.get()
        Email = self.email_add.get()
        Password = self.passowrd_add.get()
        if " " in Name:
            self.name_fill_error = Label(self.adding_frame, text= "Name shouldn't have a space", fg='red', bg='white', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'))
            self.name_fill_error.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky='w')
            self.adding_frame.after(2000, self.name_fill_error.grid_remove)
        elif Name == "" or Email == "" or Password == "":
            self.name_fill_error = Label(self.adding_frame, text='Data is empty', fg='red', bg='white', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'))
            self.name_fill_error.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky='w')
            self.adding_frame.after(2000, self.name_fill_error.grid_remove)
        elif Name in Addingpage.accountslist:
            self.name_fill_error = Label(self.adding_frame, text='Account name already exist', fg='red', bg='white', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'))
            self.name_fill_error.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky='w')
            self.adding_frame.after(2000, self.name_fill_error.grid_remove)
        else:
            self.x += 1
            with open("Addingpage.py", 'a') as A:
                A.write(f"        self.e{Name} =  Frame(self.bigframe_1, bg='white')\n")
                A.write(
                    f"        Label(self.e{Name}, text='Account Name: {Name}', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), bg='white', fg='blue').pack(anchor=W)\n")
                A.write(
                    f"        Label(self.e{Name}, text='Email: {Email}', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), bg='white', fg='black').pack(anchor=W)\n")
                A.write(
                    f"        Label(self.e{Name}, text='Password: {Password}', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), bg='white', fg='black').pack(anchor=W)\n")
                A.write(
                    f"        Label(self.e{Name}, text='', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), bg='white', fg='red').pack(anchor=W)\n")
                A.write(f"        if '{Name}' in accountslist:\n            pass\n        else:\n            accountslist.append('{Name}')\n        self.e{Name}.pack(anchor=W)\n")
                self.clearingfunction()
                self.account_added = Label(self.adding_frame, text='Your account is added', fg='green', bg='white',
                                             font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'))
                self.account_added.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky='w')
                self.adding_frame.after(2000, self.account_added.grid_remove)

    def addingpage(self):
        self.name_add = StringVar()
        self.email_add = StringVar()
        self.passowrd_add = StringVar()
        self.removeall()
        self.adding_frame = Frame(self.root, bg='white')
        self.welcome = Label(self.adding_frame, text='', width=15, bg='white').grid(row=0, rowspan=5, column=0)
        self.icongrid = Label(self.adding_frame, image=self.icon, bg='black', fg='white').grid(row=0, column=1)
        '''Name box'''
        Label(self.adding_frame, text='Name: ', bg='white', fg='black', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold')).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='e')
        self.name_add = Entry(self.adding_frame, font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), fg='blue', bg='gray', width=16)
        self.name_add.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='w')
        '''Email box'''
        Label(self.adding_frame, text='E-mail: ', bg='white', fg='black', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold')).grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='e')
        self.email_add = Entry(self.adding_frame, font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), fg='blue', bg='gray', width=32)
        self.email_add.grid(row=7, column=1)
        '''Password box'''
        Label(self.adding_frame, text='Password: ', bg='white', fg='black', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold')).grid(row=8, column=0, sticky='e')
        self.passowrd_add = Entry(self.adding_frame, font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), fg='blue', bg='gray', width=32)
        self.passowrd_add.grid(row=8, column=1)
        '''Add button'''
        add_button_adding = Button(self.adding_frame, text='Add', fg='white', font=('merriweather', 9, 'bold'), bg='black', activeforeground='green', width=20, command= self.addingfunction).grid(row=9, column=1)
        '''Back to menu button'''
        self.back_to_menu = Button(self.adding_frame, text='Back to menu', font=('merriweather', 9, 'bold'), command=self.mainmenu, fg='white', bg='black', width=10).grid(row=10, column=1)
        self.adding_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
`
```

Comment: Instead of writing lines of code, why don't you write plain text and then have your code loop over the plain text to create the labels? It's not clear what your real problem is, but having a program write code is highly unusual.

Comment: You cannot add code to a running module.  When you do an `import`, Python reads the file at that point and "pre-compiles" it to intermediate language.  After that point, it never reads the file again, even if you do another `import`.  (Picky ones will point out the `reimport` function, but that's not going to help here.)

Comment: @BryanOakley this application I made for storing anything that you want to keep away from the internet, I want the user to put his information and be permanently stored in the app even if he closed the application and opened it again so that is why I'm inserting another code "which is a label that shows him his information".

Comment: @TimRoberts the import isn't the problem because I made the application close and run again if the user inserted new input so that the code is read again, the problem is I can't insert the input in the same file that the exe is running on.

Comment: You would be better off storing the data in a file rather than trying to rewrite code. You can just create more code, but it makes the problem harder than it needs to be. Your single python file would be no more or less secure than a plain text file or a sqlite database file.

Comment: Why wouldn't store such information in a database, like a JSON file, and then just build the fields you need from that?  You shouldn't have to change the application on the fly.  That's not good design.  Among other things, you couldn't package your script as an executable.

Answer (score 0):

I used in the end SQLite database where I store information and retrieve them from there, I tried JSON file but it is not good for my purpose, even SQLite I had to manipulate and play around with it in order to make it function as I want. Here is the code at the end.

```
for i in range(1, 1000):
    c.execute(f"SELECT name FROM data WHERE id='{i}'")
    name = str(c.fetchone())
    end_slice = slice(-3)
    Name = name[end_slice][2:]
    c.execute(f"SELECT email FROM data WHERE id='{i}'")
    email = str(c.fetchone())
    Email = email[end_slice][2:]
    c.execute(f"SELECT password FROM data WHERE id='{i}'")
    password = str(c.fetchone())
    Password = password[end_slice][2:]
    if Name == "":
        continue
    Label(self.bigframe_1, text=f'Account Name: {Name}', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), bg='white',
              fg='blue').pack(anchor=W)
    Label(self.bigframe_1, text=f'Email: {Email}', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'),
              bg='white', fg='black').pack(anchor=W)
    Label(self.bigframe_1, text=f'Password: {Password}', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), bg='white',
              fg='black').pack(anchor=W)
    Label(self.bigframe_1, text='', font=('merriweather', 10, 'bold'), bg='white', fg='red').pack(anchor=W)
```

Comment: You said what did not work, but you did not say what did work